# Javascript: Optimize collision detection between a sprite and an array of sprites

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I have a canvas on which users may upload and place their own images (with transparency supported).

My goal is to not allow submissions that overlap any other existing images.

For this I would do the following (pseudo code):

```
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    const existingImage = images[i]
    for(let y = 0; y < existingImage.pixels.length; y++){  
        for(let x = 0; x < newImage.pixels.length; x++){  
            if(newImage.pixels[x] === existingImage.pixels[y])    
              return false;
        }    
    }

}

return true
```

However, the canvas resolution is 1200 x 1200. Lets say only half of all available pixels are covered then we would have 720.000 pixels that are already covered. Given a submission is like 300 x 300 (conservative estimate) then we end up comparing 720.000 existing pixels to 30.000 new pixels which gives us around 36.000.000.000 iterations. A quick test on my laptop ended up taking a minute for 2 billion iterations. 15 minutes for one collision detection would not be acceptable to me.

So my question is, how could I go about optimizing the collision detection without comprimizing accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a bounding box collision test first, then test the pixels only if bounding boxes overlap.

```
for ( var existingImage of images ) {
    if ( !(
        existingImage.left > newImage.right || 
        existingImage.right < newImage.left || 
        existingImage.top > newImage.bottom ||
        existingImage.bottom < newImage.top
    )) {
        if ( pixelsOverlap( existingImage, newImage ) ) return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, so simple yet so effective. Thanks for the suggestion I will definetely add this and see if I still have some bottlenecks

Comment: After a bit of testing, this solution avoids A LOT of computation BUT I do run in to cases where I submit a large image and it intersects another large image, ramping up iterations to a couple dozen billion iterations. Even if these cases are rare, they do come up. So the next optimization would be to actually only check the bounds that overlap instead of going ahead and comparing every pixel from each image.